# Let user filter a html table on column values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on a web app where my client wants to be able to filter a html table by column values. I've already set up a sorting feature for asc/desc but i am unsure as to how I would proceed with the structure for filtering on values. And therefore I am asking you guys regarding best practices etc.

I was thinking that I would configure filtering similar to the sorting, by passing values in the params, thought this would require more intensive santizing to prevent injections.

What i would like to achieve is a check-list for the user to select any number of existing values for the columns and then get all the records which fulfill said values.

```
<th scope="col">
                 <div class="dropdown">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" id="userDropdownButton">
                     <%=t('name')%><span class="caret"></span>
                   </button>
                   <div class="dropdown-menu" arialabelledby="userDropdownButton">
                     <%= link_to 'ASC', {:sort => "user", :direction =>"asc"} , class:"dropdown-item"%>
                     <%= link_to 'DESC', {:sort => "user", :direction =>"desc"},  class:"dropdown-item" %>
                     <%= link_to 'Filter', '#', class:"dropdown-item" %>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </th>
```

I am thankful for any help offered.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements there are plenty of library/gems you can use.

Try ransack gem https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.
This might work for you.

Comment: Preferrably i'd like if i could avoid using a gem, and i dont think ransack is exactly what im looking for. What i really want to accomplish is to let the user filter between existing values, so if i sort on name i want the user to see all names and then the user can select which names they want to see the 'records' of

Answer (score 0):

Since ransack was way more complicated than what i actually wanted i opted for a more "manual" yet cruder solution. What i ended up doing was constructing a form for all the column values that the user would be able to sort by. 
as an example this is the food-columns form

```
<ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item">
         <%=check_box_tag "food[yes][]", "1",false,class:"checkbox checkbox-primary"%><%=label_tag "Yes" %></li>
       <li class="list-group-item">
         <%=check_box_tag "food[no][]", "1",false,class:"checkbox checkbox-primary"%><%=label_tag "No" %></li>
     </ul>
     <%= submit_tag("Search")%>
```

The form is using the in-built rails AJAX(remote: true, option on the form), such that when the user submits the filter the controller recieves all the checked entries in the parameters, by manually managing and filtering them out as seen below the controller then updates the page for the user to only see the chosen entries.

```
unless params[:food].nil?
  if params[:food][:no].nil? && !params[:food][:yes].nil?
    filtered_shifts = filtered_shifts.select { |shift| shift.food == true }
  elsif params[:food][:yes].nil? && !params[:food][:no].nil?
    filtered_shifts = filtered_shifts.select { |shift| shift.food == false }
  end
end
```

I ended up with a solution that does exactly what i want, however it is quite crude and needs refactoring, which i am currently working on.